# Icon.png file error in universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

I am getting this warning while building for Release -

iPhone/iPod Touch: icon.png: icon dimensions (72 x 72) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)

This is a universal app and I have two icon.png files in my project  one in iPhone -> images and other in iPad -> images.

Also in info.plist file I set Icon file to "icon" (without any extension) I am assuming that it will find the correct file for iPhone 3 , iPhone 4 and iPad accordingly.

How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is correct for the iphone were you need 2 icons (one 57 by 57 and one 114 by 114) and it will select the right one.
But for the ipad you  need to create a 72 by 72 icon, name it in a different name and set its name in the infoplist.

**BTW** in xcode 4 you have a simple UI for setting the icons.

you can read more here :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: can you please tell me how to set iPad icon in info.plist.. because there is only one entry for icon file... and I think its for iphone3/iphone4

Comment: you simply add entries. look at the link i gave you there is an explicit explanation there.

Answer (score 15):

i had the same problem, just go to Edit Project Settings -> Build -> uncheck Compress PNG Files，and everything be OK.

Comment: Is this an Xcode bug? Glad I found this post before spending too much time trying to fix it...

Answer (score 2):

There is once I mistakenly set the project's Devices to Universal, resulting in the same error.

The fix is Target > Summary > Devices > Change to iPhone