# Icon dimensions don't meet size requirements no matter what

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to put my app on the market and am granted with this error everytime I try:

```
Ipad: icon.png: dimensions (57 x 57) don't meet the size requirements.   The icon file must be 72x72 pixels in .png format.
```

I have seen the endless posts about about modifying the .plist and also Edit Project Settings -> Build -> uncheck Compress PNG Files( [Icon.png file error in universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401184/icon-png-file-error-in-universal-app) ).  I have done both of this.  I have also went through apples guide for universal app Icons and followed that as well.  However I noticed a difference in the .plist file I have and they have (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html). (Mine has a Primary Icon attribute )  Is there something I am missing or is the apple documentation our of date?
[image]

When I change the icon to 72x72 I then get the same error except it says the icon file must be 57x57.  It seems like it's trying to use icon.png for both the iphone and ipad icon when It should be using icon-72.png for ipad and icon.png for iphone.  Is this defined somewhere else?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should have at least _four_ icon files for a universal app, 57x57, 72x72 (iPhone and iPad low resolution), 114x114, and 144x144 (iPhone and iPad Retina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the icons from my project via the file system, renamed them as suggested by NSPostWhenIdle and sree charan.  I then dragged and dropped them into the the app icon section and removed and readded the entries in the .plist via a text editor.  However this still wasn't effecient enough, I thought that removing the files from the project in the file system would remove the references in the project, THIS IS NOT TRUE.  I suggest to anyone that with icon problems after this to do what I previously stated and remove all icon references/files via the project and **NOT** the file system before re-adding.

Answer (score 12):

First of all I'm not sure if this is a rule or if it's just common practice, but your icons should start with a capital "I". Second, your iPad icon should be 72x72 not 57x57 like the iPhone icon. And finally, you're missing your iPad retina icon "Icon-72@2x.png" 144x144px.

Full break down of icons.

1. Icon.png = 57x57 iPhone non retina
2. Icon@2x.png = 114x114 iPhone retina
3. Icon-72.png = 72x72 iPad non retina
4. Icon-72@2x.png = 144x144 iPad retina

If you make sure your icons are exactly as I've listed then you won't have any problems.

If you are still experiencing problems after making these changes then try deleting all icon images from the project, and deleting the icon keys from your .plist file.
Then re-add the images to the project by dragging them directly to their corresponding placeholder in the summary tab of Xcode's navigator.

[image]

Comment: Amazingly, this worked! I had to delete and re-add them, like you said. None of the other solutions worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Deleting it and adding it didn't help. When you add the image to No image specified thing, xcode should automatically add it to infoplist

Answer (score 6):

Well, I agree with @NSPostWhenIdle, But as far as the Naming conventions he is right, if you are adding directly to the plist,

But when it is concerned with Xcode , from Xcode 4.2, when you open the target settings -> Summary

I hope that you are using Xcode later than 4.2

And when you mouse over the App Icons section, it will show the size of icons and right click there and add icons. Xcode itself fix the names for your icons according to the size of the icons which you are selecting like this

[image: For Normal Image]

[image: For Retina Image]

So, No matter of fighting with the naming conventions of iCons, and if you add like this, these icon names are fixed my Xcode itself and these icons are automatically added to the plist File as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon.png is probably not exactly 57x57. in finder, right click on the icon.png, get info. If it still says 57x57, then I am not sure why its throwing that error.

I had a similar issue when my icon.png was 57x56 (which I had never checked until xcode whined).

IF these dont work, restart your Xcode and or Mac, make a clean build.

Comment: I added the exact error messages I am getting...I tried restarting my machine and Xcode to no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add (for others finding this question) that I recently ran into this error, but in my case it was complaining that 76x76 did not meet the requirement of 72x72, which didn't make any sense to me since our iPad app is iOS 7 only and therefore according to all official documentation only requires icons of size 76x76 and 152x152.

> Icon dimensions (76 x 76) don't meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 72x72 pixels, in .png format.

Anyhow it turned out the person uploading the binary was using an older version of Application Loader (from Xcode 4.6) and this check was happening client-side before the upload even took place.

Submitting the same binary using the newer Application Loader from Xcode 5 had no problem!